# Why does a font on Option keep changing in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, fonts

After installing Visual Studio, I set up the option for Font as Verdaan. And the font, i feel like once or two per day at least, has kept changing to as a default. I already have checked someone asked to Microsoft saying they would fix the problem, and nothing to see.

Is there anyone solving out this issue? Or I haven't seen the solution? Please share it if so!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to uncheck **Synchronize settings across devices when signed into Visual Studio** in  Accounts options:

[image]

Comment: You are my star!! Thanks a lot!