# VS2019 Tools -> Options -> Font and Colors never saved

Tags: settings, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019 CE I try to change the font size for Text Editor.
I go to Tools -> Options -> Envirounment -> Fonts and Colors, change font size and click OK.
Font size changed and I can work.
After I close and open VS2019 these settings lost and again set to defaults.
What can be the problem? How to permanently solve it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140572/why-does-a-font-on-option-keep-changing-in-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue in Visual Studio 2019 application, see a [similar problem discussed here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/528502/changed-fonts-and-color-settings-not-saved.html).

And here's a workaround from the same thread, but not an official fix from MS.

> I was experiencing almost the same issues: everything was using the
>   "general" defaults rather than the c# defaults (which I wanted). I set
>   to the c# defaults but they wouldn’t save upon reopening vs. However,
>   any font changes remained after reopening and any colour changes
>   remained - for example, I set plaintext - background to "black" rather
>   than "default" - which saved. I then tried switching the font colour
>   to white, and all the default c# colour options saved.

Comment: Unfortunately none of above help me.